# S3 - Revoking "full_control" permission from owned object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While writing S3 server implementation, ran into question I can't really find answer anywhere.

For example I'm the bucket owner, and as well owner of uploaded object.

In case I revoke "full_control" permission from object owner (myself), will I be able to access and modify that object?
What's the expected behaviour in following example:

```
s3cmd setacl --acl-grant full_control:ownerID s3://bucket/object
s3cmd setacl --acl-revoke full_control:ownerID s3://bucket/object
s3cmd setacl --acl-grant read:ownerID s3://bucket/object
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's the official answer from AWS support:

> T**he short answer for that question would be yes, the bucket/object
>   owner has permission to read and update the bucket/object ACL,
>   provided that there is no bucket policy attached that explicitly
>   removes these permissions from the owner.** For example, the following
>   policy would prevent the owner from doing anything on the bucket,
>   including changing the bucket's ACL:
>
> ```
>  {
>   "Id": "Policy1531126735810",
>   "Version": "2012-10-17",
>   "Statement": [
>     {
>       "Sid": "Example bucket policy",
>       "Action": "s3:*",
>       "Effect": "Deny",
>       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>",
>       "Principal": "*"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> However, as root (bucket owner) you'd still have permission to delete
>   that policy, which would then restore your permissions as bucket owner
>   to update the ACL.
>
> By default, all S3 resources, buckets, objects and subresources, are
>   private; only the resource owner, which is the AWS account that
>   created it, can access the resource[1]. As the resource owner (AWS
>   account), you can optionally grant permission to other users by
>   attaching an access policy to the users.
>
> Example: let's say you created an IAM user called -S3User1-, and gave
>   it permission to create buckets in S3 and update its ACLs. The user in
>   question then goes ahead and create a bucket and name it
>   "s3user1-bucket". After that, he goes further and remove List objects,
>   Write objects, Read bucket permission and Write bucket permissions
>   from the root account on the ACL section. At this point, if you log in
>   as root and attempt to read the objects in that bucket, an "Access
>   Denied" error will be thrown. However, as root you'll be able to go to
>   the "Permissions" section of the bucket and add these permissions
>   back.

Answer (score 1):

These days it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

You should typically avoid using object-level permissions to control access. It is best to make them all "**bucket-owner full control**" and then use **Bucket Policies** to grant access to the bucket or a path.

If you wish to provide per-object access, it is recommended to use [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which give time-limited access to a private object. Once the time expires, the URL no longer works. Your application would be responsible for determining whether a user is permitted to access an object, and then generates the pre-signed URL (eg as a link or href on an HTML page).

Comment: This is interesting. Can you provide some links to come to this conclusion? Because as per my exp I think the other way. Having atomic access is useful and beneficial to avoid any accidents (in most cases).

Comment: Object-level permissions can only grant simple permissions to other AWS users. It is not useful for providing web-based access. I've added another option above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer John.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, still I didn't got the answer what permissions will have bucket owner if I revoke "full_control" permission? ;)

Comment: I don't know. Try it for yourself and let us know what you find!